# How to display a messgae on top of each activity?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am checking the internet connection in my application, when the internet is not accessible I want to display a small popup message to the user that you're offline.

I tried to solve the issue by using `AlertDialog` and `AlertDialog.Builder`, and I have also searched through different solution on the internet but no solution resolve my issue. I am trying to do this by the following method.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View alertdialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nointernetdialogue, null);
        builder.setView(alertdialog);
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams alertTop = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
        alertTop.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.START;
        alertTop.x = 100;
        alertTop.y = 100;
        dialog.show();
```

The result I want.

[image]

Comment: if you want to display only one line, you can use https://github.com/AndreiD/TSnackBar

Comment: This is not what I want, I want to display it for every activity when the user is offline.

Comment: you can create application class by which display topbar on every activity.

Answer (score 2):

Create BaseActivity which shall implement Broadcast Receiver regarding network connectivity checks. Whenever network connectivity goes off, show the SnackBar/Alert. 
Let all your other activities extend this Base activity.

Answer (score 0):

Alert dialog looks like a over kill just have a TextView and show and hide it on network change.

Comment: But how it will stay on each avtivity?

Comment: Well i don't know your architecture but normally you should not have a lot of activities you should have just fragments that you swap in the activity and this way you have a text view that is in the activity and its just above the fragment. But in the case of you having a lot of activities you can add it in all of them or you can just add a TextView dynamically in the source code.

Comment: I am using activites and I want to display this message on top of each activity when user is offline, and I want to add TextView in every activity, please suggest another way.

Comment: Should this message stay until the connection has returned?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want. And I am already checking for the connection in Asynctask I only want to notify user through this message.

Comment: Well you should send a notification to the activity that is currently being presented and in the activity you should display/hide the TextView in my opinion you can also make a activity that has this textview by default and have all your activities just inherit it but in your case i would just add the textview to all of the activities dynamically. Sorry no other solution comes to mind

Comment: Perfect! I will implement your suggested solution then check the solution accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this example [Click here](https://github.com/RamKumar-27/Android-Internet-callback-Notifier)

here i am using `BroadcastReceiver` to find the Wifi and Mobile data status

By this you can access the Network state anywhere un the App

Comment: Explain please!

Comment: here i am using `ConnectivityManager` to get which network is currently active(Wifi or mobile data) and also the status of the active network wether its connected or not.  And the `BroadCastReceiver` which find the status changed. And have one Global `interface` to get the callback which get it from anywhere. That interface initialize in our singleton class

Comment: I already implemented network checking method I just want to display a message on top when the network is not active or inaccessible.

Comment: Create a BaseClass for `Activity` and `Fragment` and just declare the interface to there. in that `override` method you can add whatever you want (Dialog, snackBar, any other Popup )

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `BaseActivity` that checks internet connection and shows alert dialog if needed. All activities that you want to show alert dialog should extended from `BaseActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with top SnackBar , there is the code

```
Snackbar snack =    Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Online", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
View view = snack.getView();
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params =(FrameLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams(); params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
view.setLayoutParams(params); 
snack.show();
```